# prevent body scroll on modal close

Tags: modal-dialog

I have a simple html/css modal dialog that I close with a button and onclick event handlers in javascript.  When the modal window is closed, the body of the site scrolls to the top of the screen.  I need to prevent this.
Here is my code:

```js
function modalClose() {
  if (location.hash == '#log_in') {
    location.hash = '';
  }
}
// Handle ESC key (key code 27)
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    modalClose();
  }
});
var modal = document.querySelector('#log_in');
// Handle click on the modal container
modal.addEventListener('click', modalClose, false);
// Prevent event bubbling if click occurred within modal content body
modal.children[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
  height: auto;
  width: 75%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -11px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  text-indent: 0px;
}
.close:hover {
  background: navy;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://thomaswurdinger.com/Store_Reboot/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://thomaswurdinger.com/Store_Reboot/js/js.js"></script>
<link href="https://thomaswurdinger.com/Store_Reboot/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="log_in" class="modalDialog">
 <div>
  <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
  <div>Modal Contents</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason I can't get the code snippet to work. sorry.

Comment: When I change the line :                                                                            if (location.hash == '#log_in') {
    location.hash = '';
  } to if (location.hash == '#log_in') {
    location.hash = '*pagename*';
  } it works.

Answer (score 0):

I changed :

```
if (location.hash == '#log_in') {
location.hash = '';
}
```

to:

```
if (location.hash == '#log_in') {
location.hash = 'pagename.php';
}
```